# How to remove hyper links from reference list (bibliography)? - {\hypersetup{nolinks=true} not working!

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, lncs, hyperlink

I am new to Latex and I am using Overleaf. I wonder how I can remove hyperlinks from my reference list (bibliography)?

I am using the Hyperref package, and use the \cite to reference documents which are in a separate, large Bibtex file. I am using `\hypersetup{nolinks=true}` in the header to remove links, but it does not work!

Here is how I load and use the packages (the header of my file):

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{nolinks=true}

%\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
%\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu
```

Is it possible that this happens because I am using the LNCS template? Because it tells the references to follow its style, where it wants to add the bibliography (reference list):

```
\bibliographystyle{splncs04}
\bibliography{my_ref.bib}
```

Thanks

PS:Also, here is how my current bibliography looks like. I want the links gone:
[image]

Comment: I get no links with your class and the hyperref option. Show a screenshot of  a link you are getting.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Added to the original question

Comment: There is nothing that shows that there are active links. Or do you want the printed text `http://...` to go away?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that's what I want.

Comment: That has nothing to do with hyperref, it only makes the links active, it doesn't print them. Your bibliography style inserts the urls and to really suppress them you should either change the bst or use a different style. You could try  `\makeatletter\def\url@#1{}\makeatother` before the bibliography, but you will probably get some stray commas in the bibliography.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks a lot! I can't like or +1 your comments (probably because I am a new user), but I appreciate your help. You know what I did? I went through the BibTex file, found and replaced all 'url' and 'doi's with '---' and that fixed the issue for now! :))

Comment: I hope you made a backup - in case that you need the doi and url in some future article.

Comment: Yes, this was my thesis bibliography and I had more than 1k references in it (in the file, not the thesis!). I used Mendeley for my thesis. So, I have online and offline backups. Even this Bibtex file itself was a backup at some point! :) Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: It's an odd suggestion, better to remove the links in PDF using Acrobat Professional...

Answer (score -1):

I am still new to Latex myself but what I have found is this

```
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}
```

This will not remove the link, but hide the colour of the links in the printed version (pdf) which already might be what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work either!